# Use kafka with java code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have an Kafka instance working with Zookeeper. I'm actually able to make a producer consumer using the command line on windows, I write some string on the producer and they are displayed on the consumer.
My goal is now to realize a file "transfer" using Kafka with some Java code. I want to "read" and then "write" a file using Kafka.

To realize this, I took the code available on this repository :

- [FileStreamSinkConnector](https://insight.io/github.com/apache/kafka/blob/HEAD/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSinkConnector.java)
- [FileStreamSinkTask](https://insight.io/github.com/apache/kafka/blob/HEAD/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSinkTask.java)
- [FileStreamSourceConnector](https://insight.io/github.com/apache/kafka/blob/HEAD/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceConnector.java)
- [FileStreamSourceTask](https://insight.io/github.com/apache/kafka/blob/HEAD/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceTask.java)

From what I understand, SinkConnector and TaksConnector will write the file while SourceConnector and SourceTask will read it.

My problem is that I don't know how to use this code in a main and how to use it with the kafka instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier you were using Kafka console producer and consumer. Whereas the connectors you have mentioned in your question are part of Kafka connect (you can read more about it [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html).

To make use of source and sink connectors you will have to configure and start connect workers. I presume you are trying to run the whole process in standalone mode.

[Quick start page](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html) has steps explaining the usage of these connectors. I hope it helps.